# jqgrid is freaking out when gets 2 ajax calls

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid for my app and it works fine, I just have problem when the jqgrid gets 2 different ajax calls one by one but fast, I want it to just relate to the second ajax call, but it freaks out. Someone have an idea to resolve this?

i can't give a peek on the code, but i mean that he try to reload the data and meanwhile i press anther button and want him to reload anther data instead. i look at Fiddler and the 2 ajax calls gets fine

Comment: What do you mean by 2 ajax calls? Maybe a peek at the code?

Comment: i can't give a peek on the code, but i mean that he try to reload the data and meanwhile i press anther button and want him to reload anther data instead. i look at Fiddler and the 2 ajax calls gets fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill the first request as a part of your second call.  See [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery) as an example of killing an Ajax request.

Comment: thanks, its may help, but how can i get my previous ajax call so i can call .abort?

Comment: This should be a more specific example to a jqGrid request cancel. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016583/how-do-i-add-a-cancel-button-to-my-jqgrid

Comment: thanks, it's wasn't easy but your answer eventually lead me to the solution.